# Is there a proton gradient across the cell membrane, just like for the mitochondrial membrane?

Tags: cell-biology, electrophysiology

Mitochondria have a proton gradient, is there also a proton gradient between cells and the extracellular medium?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please provide more detail — are you only interested in proton gradients or also other electrochemical gradients? In general, we expect you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). In particular, since it appears you can easily answer this using reliable sources online this question seems to fit this sites criteria for ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). (Note this can apply to questions not assigned as homework.) Thanks! 

Comment: Cell has potassium and sodium gradients obviously. I am not asking about chemical gradients in general. The question is on if there are proton gradients between cells and extracellular fluid.

Comment: That's not answered on your link there. So, you can edit your comment and remove that part.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Comments are ephemeral and often unread. ———— I recommend that you delete "similar gradient" from your post or otherwise make clear in the body that you only care about proton gradients. In addition, if you aren't interested in the somewhat trivial answer that many (maybe all?) bacteria (e.g. the ancestors of mitochondria) create a proton gradient you will want to specify what types of cells you do care about.

Comment: And your name is Mitchell! (At least that’s my hypothesis.) So ask yourself (or research) how the proton gradient is produced, and why. And then consider whether what you propose would be likely

Comment: @tyersome Yes, bacteria have proton gradients. Question on eukaryotic cells mainly, could have specified that but it's in some way implied since it compares "the cell" to mitochondria.